# while displaying a table instead of showing NULL the field should be empty. can we do it through SQL or angularjs..?

Tags: java, mysql, angularjs

While fetching data from database some fields are NUll in my tables. So while I am trying to display using HTML and Angularjs the same result is displayed. while my requirement is rather than displaying NULL , the field should be empty

Comment: I guess your data has attributes with values null as string("null") but not null that's why angular shows it as literal null.Instead while you set your data into returning object after fetching from DB in the backend,try setting those values as null instead String value of null.

Comment: I have used COALESCE() in my mysql query for which I am getting NULL value . It worked

Answer (score 1):

Use an [ng-if](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngIf) to filter your incorrect values.

Below a simple example of what you could do:

```
<div ng-repeat="data in datas">
    <span ng-if="data != null">{{data.value}}</span>
</div>
```

Another way can be to filter your null values server-side: if they are null, why sending them to the client?

### Edit 1

Regarding OP's problem, this ng-if resolved his issue:

```
<tbody ng-repeat="x in data"> 
   <tr ng-if="x != null">
      <td>{{x.value}}</td>
   </tr> 
</tbody>
```

Because using the earlier ng-if

```
 <div ng-repeat="x in data" ng-if="x != null">
    <span>{{x.value}}</span>
</div>
```

was failing due to the fact the **first** element in "data" was null (and then, no ng-repeat was compiled in the dom).

Comment: I am not using div here I am using table <tr ng-repeat="data in datas"> and <td>{{data.value}}</td></tr>

Comment: I tried using NVL in mysql from server side but it didn't work

Comment: so try this way: <tr ng-repeat="data in datas" ng-if="data != null"><td>{{data.value}}</td></tr>.  also: what you use as backend? Java? can't you filter your data from java code?

Comment: I tried but there is no result <tr ng-repeat="x in data" ng-if="x != null"> <td>{{x.value}}</td></tr>. yea I use java

Comment: maybe your first element is breaking your entire ng-repeat. try this instead: <tbody ng-repeat="x in data"> <tr ng-if="x != null"><td>{{x.value}}</td> </tr> </tbody>

Comment: yeah of course: you should do it in the backend if it's a simple null filter. can you post your backend code?

Comment: (select oeps.employee_id,oe.full_name,oe.office_email_add,oass.department_id, ods.department_name ,oass.supervisor_id,oee.full_name manager
  from osi_employee_profile_staging oeps,osi_employee oe, osi_assignments oass  Left Join osi_departments ods on ods.department_id = oass.department_id
Left Join osi_employee oee on oee.employee_id = oass.supervisor_id   where oe.employee_id = oeps.employee_id and oass.employee_id = oeps.employee_id and oeps.`status`='N' order by oeps.employee_id ).        this is my query where i am getting NULL values for office_email. I am retrieving values from DB

Comment: Yeah, that's the SQL. But angularjs doesn't connect directly to a Database: your SQL it's probably used by a java code. Can you post that ?

Comment: Yeah it worked. I have tried the different way as you said earlier by using ng-if . Thank you

Comment: If my answer resolved your issue, please accept the answer: at least we don't leave this question open on SO.

Comment: yea I am new to stack over flow. I don't have reputation to accept your answer, but the answer was recorded.

Answer (score 1):

You can create angular filter.

Just add in

```
<td>{{data.value | nullFilter}}</td>
```

and define filter as

```
app.filter('nullFilter', function(){
    return function(value){
        if(value == null || value =='null'){
            return "No data found";
        }

        return value;  
    }    
});
```

Example - http://fiddle.jshell.net/z51obxvc/